# Effect of plane isometry on punctured disc

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to confirm if I am correct. Due to the rotational symmetry of open unit disc $D$, it suffices to study only translations on $D$ out of the  four plane isometries? This is because, every other isometric transformation(like reflection, rotation, glide reflection) can just be viewed as the effect of a translation. Am I correct? The same will hold for the punctured disc?

EDIT: I am sorry question is not clear. I am giving my exact problem here. I want to evaluate certain integral say $\int f(x) dx$ on on every congruent copy of punctured disc in the plane. This means I need to evaluate $\int f(g(x)) dx$ on the unit punctured disc where $g$ is the isometry of a plane, right? What my question is that whether it suffices to take $g$ as the translation only because  the effect of other three isometries  on punctured disk can be viewed as the special cases of translation, due to the 'nice' symmetry of punctured disc? Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: There are no translations on $D$ in Euclidean geometry. Are you perhaps referring to hyperbolic geometry using the Poincaré metric? And if you are, then I still do not understand your question: What do you mean by the assertion that "every other isometric transformation... can just be viewed as the effect of a translation"? What kind of "effect" did you have in mind?

Comment: We have four isometries of plane: I am asking whether we can view Rotation, Reflection as a Translation in the following way?1)Rotating disc ≡ No translation. 2) Reflection of disc about some line ≡ Translation by some l(say?

Comment: No, you cannot view them that way. Every (non-identity) isometry of the plane falls into **exactly one** of those four classes, there are no overlaps between them as you suggest. In particular, a reflection about some line is not a translation in any way. Nonetheless, I fear that I still misunderstand your question, because a particular open unit disc $D$ in the plane has no special relation to isometries of the plane.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am sorry question is not clear. I am giving my exact problem here. I want to evaluate certain integral say $\int f(x) dx$ on on every congruent copy of punctured disc in the plane. This means I need to evaluate $\int f(g(x)) dx$ on the unit punctured disc where $g$ is the isometry of a plane, right? What my question is that whether it suffices to take $g$ as translation only because other the effect of other three isometries  on punctured disk can be viewed as the special cases of translation?